Can I use unorthodox methods to worship Devi Maa?
Recently I experienced a very intense devotion towards Devi Maa, I surrendered myself to her completely. I'm consumed by a deep longing for her, I don't know what they call this but I feel like I want to be by Her side and do her seva everyday. However I have had very bad experiences with the 'correct' form of worship which I feel immerses myself more into the real world than into Her worship (as in standard pujas and worship methods).
My concern now is that I wish to do Her worship even during periods and offer her everything I eat, including cooked chicken and egg. Of course, we know that in the scriptures this is forbidden. But I genuinely cannot imagine not thinking of her everyday and not offering her what I love. I feel She is my mother, how can I not give my mother the delicious things I eat?
I found that animals sacrificed to the Devi are acceptable but I cannot sacrifice them myself. Would my seva still be valid? I have asked Her to guide me but kindly request your opinions
Thank you

When you surrender completely to the divine mother, what really matters and is most important is the Bhaav ... !

Offer in front of the image flowers,burning incense, lighted lamps along with some food items (even sugar cubes or milk will do).  Nobody sacrifices in homes. That must be happening only in some temples.

If you are a devotee of Maa, then you must follow the scriptures because that is the will of Maa, and you must respect that if you are a devotee. Regarding the worshipping during periods, shastras are clear, during periods one must not touch the vigraha and must perform Mansik Puja and meditate. Chickens cannot be offered to Maa, Mutton can be offered after proper ritualised bali, I would suggest getting yourself a proper tantrik diksha, your guru will tell you the proper methods. If you practice through proper methods it is possible that you may even get proper vision of Maa
